# What's wrong with my navigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to set *title* property of current *navigationItem.backBarItem* not relative to title of previous view. So I use this method:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=barButtonItem;
```

But I found it doesn't act as I expect in some situation.

**USE TOPITEM IN VIEW B**

[image]

**USE BACKITEM IN VIEW B**

[image]

And I found that `self.navigationController.navigationBar.items` (I think it is a stack of UINavigationItems)seems not correct.

In view A, put `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` also leads to different behavior.

So what is wrong with my code? Should I explicit access to *self.navigationItem* to force it initialized(event I don't use it directly)?

**CODE: thanks for your patience**

**VIEW A:**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
}
```

**VIEW B:**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.title=@"B";
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"toA"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self
                                 action:nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=buttonItem;
}
```

**VIEW C:**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.title=@"C";
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
    UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"toB"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self
                                 action:nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=buttonItem;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set the backbutton use

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=buttonItem;
```

If you want to set the title of the backbutton use *leftbarbutton*
in `viewwillAppear`

```
 [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];

 UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"toA"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(back)];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=buttonItem;
```

**back action**

```
-(void)back
{    
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

or you can try these

viewwillappear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                         initWithTitle:@"toA"
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                         target:self
                                         action:@selector(back)];
           self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=buttonItem;
    }


-(void)back
        {    
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }
```

Comment: Not correct. `self.navigationItem` will set the _backBarButton_ of **next** view, not current. That means in view B it will show **back**, and in view C it will show **toA**. Tested.

Comment: Thank you. Have tested edited version, also not work... Did I miss something??

Comment: In every viewcontroller first you need to write     self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
then

Comment: Yes, it works... But I think there is a better way... Would you please tell me why mine not work. Any way, thank you very much.

Comment: welcome it will be appreciable if you upvote and i have to see why your code is not working will get back to you